# How do I look for a specific process and skip if it's not running?

Tags: command-line, scripts, process

I wanted to stop a particular process and proceed further, also if the same process is not running just wanted to print a message saying this process is not running and proceed further. How do I do that? I am trying to do this in a shell script...

I found this, but I'm not sure it's correct:

```bash
if pgrep -x "pm2 status | grep mobile-first-Mobile-First-branch" > /dev/null
then 
    echo " service is not running"
    pm2 stop /az/srvr/pm2/pm2.conf.json --only mobile-first-Mobile-First-branch
fi
```

Comment: You can verify (become sure if it's correct) by running it.  Keep in mind what you want and expect for it to do.  Compare with what it actually does when you run it and make a reference to where it fails.  If it doesn't do what you are trying, a reference to where it fails will help us to have a clearer understanding of your intentions.

Comment: I agree with @L.D.James that you can verify it by running it.  `pgrep` is a safe application to run as it is looking through running processes and finding what you are looking for.  However, the code is wrong as it is trying to look for the output from the `pm2` application but it is encased in quotes.  It needs to be a sub command like `if pgrep -x $(pm2 status | grep mobile-first-Mobile-First-branch) > /dev/null`.  I am  not sure that this is exactly what you are trying to do.  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1023332/edit) your question and add details of what you're trying to do.